# Error VB DoCmd.RunSQL Update

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to run an update query in VB in Access and I get a syntax error in the Update statement. Can anyone help please?

```
Sub Update_Project()
Dim ProjectID, ProjectName, ProjectManager, sql_text as string

ProjectID = Wkbk.Sheets(1).Range("C5").Value

ProjectName = Wkbk.Sheets(1).Range("D5").Value
ProjectManager = Wkbk.Sheets(1).Range("E5").Value

sql_text = "UPDATE Projects (set ProjName, ProjManager) = '" & ProjectName & "," & ProjectManager & "' where ProgrammeID = " & ProjectID
DoCmd.RunSQL(sql_text)
End Sub
```

I think he error may be in the concatenation of the fields to update, but I can't work it out.

Thanks!

Comment: You will first need to debug your update statement so that it works outside of VBA. Hint: `UPDATE <table> SET <field1> = <value1>, <field2> = <value2>`. Afterwards, you'll need to get the `'` apostrophes right around `ProjectName` and `ProjectManager`. Third: it is better to use query parameters.

Comment: Thanks for that. It is basically what PaulFrancis has done for me below, to puy the apostrophes and double quotes accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the syntax of the UPDATE statement muddled up. Also you need to explicitly declare variables that will save you a lot of hassle. The following is what you need.

```
Sub Update_Project()
    Dim ProjectID As Long, ProjectName As String, ProjectManager As String, sql_text As String

    ProjectID = Wkbk.Sheets(1).Range("C5").Value

    ProjectName = Wkbk.Sheets(1).Range("D5").Value
    ProjectManager = Wkbk.Sheets(1).Range("E5").Value

    sql_text = "UPDATE Projects SET ProjName = '" & ProjectName & "', ProjManager = '" & ProjectManager & _
               "' WHERE ProgrammeID = " & ProjectID
    DoCmd.RunSQL sql_text
End Sub
```

Comment: PaulFrancis. Brilliant answer. It has worked perfectly. I have marked your answer as the accepted one.